# Decode Values in Controller or View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Please consider this scenario: in some business domain there is some simple and constant options that we may implement them as combo box or radio buttons.

For example consider this sample for status combo box:

```
(Bad , 1), 
(Medium , 2), 
(Good , 3), 
(Well , 4)
```

For this base information we create a static method (or property) of type `List` in a class and for this simple and constant we did not save them in database.

Now consider we want to create a read-only view and in model we use `StatusID` but we should decode this ID for showing it's text. I know (according to my incomplete information) 2 solution:

1. Create a viewmodel and add a `StatusText` property to it and in my control decode `StatusID` using my static method
2. Pass my model to view and decode it there

I want to know what the best practice is for such scenarios.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry That is not enum and I want to show Key-Value pair

Comment: I know its not an `enum`. I am asking why not use an enum (and make it far easier)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks That's true and we can use `enum` but we should decode it's ID again and the problem still remian. maybe my information is not complete for your approach

Comment: What do you mean _decode it_? There is no 'decoding' required

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please provide a solution? Maybe I did not understand your solution. Thanks

Comment: Refer the answer by Mihail Stancescu. Just create an enum `public enum Status { Bad = 1, Medium = 2, .... }` and make you property `public Status Status { get; set; }` and in the view `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Status)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It create a `DropDownList` but I want just a `Label`

Comment: Then all you need is `@Model.Status` in the view to display the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make them as `Enum` and use in the view `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m=>m.StatusId, m=> m.MyEnum)`.

If you want custom display labels use the `DisplayAttribute` on the enum members.

**Update**

If you only want to show the value in a label, I would still recommend using an `Enum` and in the view: `<div>(@Model.Status.ToString() , @((int)Model.Status))</div>`. You can replace `<div>` with whatever element you need.

Comment: I thinks It create a `DropDownList` but I want just a `Label`